# How can I print a string depending on the list value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print a string depending on the values in the list. Values can be 0 or 1. For example:

```
# Example [a,b,c] = [0,0,1] -- > print str c
# [1,0,1] -- print str a and str c

index_list = [0,0,1] # Example      
str_a = "str_a"
str_b = "str_b"
str_c = "str_c"

print str
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for condition, string in zip(index_list, [str_a, str_b, str_c]):
    if condition:
        print string
```

Since the question is tagged as [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7), [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) produces a new list of tuples. If you have a large list of indexes and strings, consider using [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), or upgrade to python 3.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39568508/2681632) provides a standard lib function exactly for this pattern, removing the need for explicit condition checking.

Comment: How can I that string convert in list ? For example:`string[0] = a, string[1] = c...with .split() ` I can't split it

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. How come split isn't working for you? Do you wan't to create a list of filtered strings?

Comment: after the `print string ` I got for example string:
`a`
`c`
and now I want convert that into a list. Then I have so one list: `string[0] = "a" ` and `string[1] = "b"`.

Comment: For that do something like `compressed_list = list(compress(list_of_strings, index_list))` instead of printing (`compress` returns an iterator in py2 too, so wrap it with `list`).

Answer (score 7):

Here's an elegant way. Use the compress function in itertools:

```
import itertools as it
l1 = [1, 0, 1]
l2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
for item in it.compress(l2, l1):
    print item
```

Output:

```
=================== RESTART: C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/stack.py ===================
a
c
>>>
```

Comment: Excellent. Have missed this entirely.

Comment: This is the right way as itertools.compress is there exactly for this.

Comment: Haha! I have never used compress in my life. Who knew I would find an opportunity today.

Comment: Please add the link to itertools.compress to the answer so it will be complete :) Here: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = [str_a,str_b,str_c]
>>> b=  [0,0,1]
>>> ','.join(i for i,j in zip(a,b) if j)
'str_c'
```